# Mac OSX - Getting Segmentation Faults on every C++ Program (Even Hello World) after Yosemite Update

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I recently just upgraded to OSX Yosemite on my Mac and while I'm not sure if this is the cause, it does seem suspicious that suddenly all of My C++ Programs throw a Segmentation Fault.

I even tried the basic of all basic "Hello World" programs and I still get a Segmentation Fault. Literally, every single C++ program does the same.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

I installed the Xcode updates to see if that would remedy the situation but no luck. I'm curious, is anyone else out there having the same problem? Regardless of Yosemite, have you had this problem where your Mac throws Segmentation faults for **everything**?

I should add, I'm compiling with g++

Comment: At which line it throws the error ? can  you post the output of `strace`

Comment: Try reinstalling your C++ compiler suite (Clang or GCC)

Comment: @g4ur4v I'm sorry I'm not familiar with strace. I've tried determining the seg faulting line via gdb, but I can't get anything past "Segmentation Fault: 11". I'm going to attempt to reinstall the C++ compiler

Comment: Alright well apparently when updating to Yosemite, it totally wiped out my command line tools. So I reinstalled those via the Apple developer portal (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) specifically for OSX 10.10. However, XCode still won't register the command line tools. They don't appear anywhere in under "Components" in the Downloads tab in the Xcode preferences pane. Super confused what's going on, but working through it.

Comment: I think you go to the AppStore and install Xcode from there, then you do `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 11):

After a few more tries I have found a workaround from here:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/libtool-patches/2014-09/msg00002.html

Simply

```
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9
```

or

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
```

Happily works after that. However, proper bug fixes should be forthcoming from libtool, so watch the progress there.

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107) If you have a different question, please ask it by clicking the ["Ask Question" button at the top of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you have the exact same issue as this one, when you have enough reputation, you can [upvote the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), or [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it. You can also "star" the question as a favorite, in which case the system will notify you of any new answers.

Comment: This is just to comment in August 2015 indicating I still had the same issue in OSX 10.10.4 with gfortran throwing up segmentation faults (even on gfortran --version). Using the second export command in this post fixed the issue. I think part of the problem is that libtool is from an old version of XCode (see [here](http://www.jattcode.com/installing-autoconf-automake-libtool-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion/)). I tried to install libtools from MacPorts, but it seems to install in a different location under glibtools.

Answer (score 0):

My g++ version is (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.4_5+universal) 4.7.4

I ran  `sudo port selfupdate` followed by `sudo port upgrade outdated`

This worked for me

also you can run `launchctl setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.9` to make it permanent.